# Adding Boost to XCode: Where do I find libboost_serialization.dylib?

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I've downloaded Boost and am trying to get it into my XCode C++ project. (I only need `filesystem`, by the way.) I'm trying to follow [these](http://buddypanda.com/?p=10) instructions but am finding them unclear.

Where it says to put `/path/to/boost/include`, I put `/Documents/boost_1_57_0/boost`; and where it says to put `/path/to/boost/lib`, I put `/Documents/boost_1_57_0/libs`.

(1) I'm not sure whether the above is correct. Is it?

(2) The next step tells me to add the `.dylib` file to the project. Where can I find that file? I've looked in almost every subfolder of `boost_1_57_0` and can't find it.

(3) If the instructions on that site suck, can someone here give me better instructions?

Comment: You probably only downloaded boost, and didn't actually compile it, which is why you don't have a `.dylib` - `bootstrap` followed by `b2`. You can try to install it; which will, I think, put it into /usr/local. Alternatively, use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install boost, and point the headers it at `/usr/local/include` and the libraries at `/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

When you install boost library through command window, it will tell you where the header files and lib files are stored. Instead of /Documents/boost_1_57_0/libs use /Documents/boost_1_57_0/stage/lib.You will find libboost_serialization.dylib in /Documents/boost_1_57_0/stage/lib. It should work for you.
Also go through this link :

https://buddypanda.com/?p=10

This has better explanation.